# Capture All memory accesses of a process in Linux

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, trace

I need a trace of memory accesses of a process for simulation.
For this purpose i need a tool that captures and logs all memory accesses of a process.
is there any program to do so? if there is not, can I do that with modifications in linux kernel?

Comment: To trace literally every memory access, you need a CPU emulator. If page-granularity is enough, you could get by with a kernel extension.

Comment: You might be able to make yourself a Valgrind tool to do the job - memcheck or cachegrind may be a good starting point?